# Repositorio do Pentaho Data Integration não aparece no PDI

Tags: data-warehouse

Boa noite.

Estou com um problema constante com o PDI. As vezes quando abro o spoon.bat ele não carrega o repositório e nem habilita a opção para conectar em um repositório. Já pesquisei em diversos fóruns e até agora as soluções passadas não funcionaram para mim. Já exclui a pasta .kettle do perfil do usuário (sem sucesso) e também já configurei o repositories.xml para UTF-8 (também sem sucesso). Alguém tem uma outra sugestão ai?

Preciso ficar fazendo logoff e login umas 10 vezes para carregar a lista de repositórios.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para mim a seguinte solução deu certo. Feche seu PDI, Navegue até a seguinte pasta da sua instalação do PDI: ..\data-integration\system\karaf\caches\spoon\ Pode ser que haja pastas data-1, data-2 ... entre em cada uma delas e delete todo o conteúdo, **veja bem, delete o conteúdo da pasta, não a pasta inteira**. Execute o Spoon.bat Caso não de certo ha outras tentativas possiveis que possa resolver esse problema.

Comment: Procurando por outras alternativas, alguns usuários reportaram possivel incompatibilidade com a versão do JDK, e que neste caso, era para ser utilizada a versão 1.8 do JDK (Java). Pessoalmente eu utlizo a versão jdk1.8.0_131 e jre1.8.0_181 para o PDI. Caso você não utilize JAVA para nenhuma outra função que não o PDI, vale a pena tentar. Reiterando que a primeira solução resolveu o problema para mim, e eu utilizo estas versões de java.

Comment: Senhores, identifiquei o problema!
Se o caso de vocês forem na criação de um "File Repositury", isso acontece se no cominho do diretório os nomes das pastas conterem espaços ou qualquer tipo de acentuação.
Renomeiem as pastas retirando acentos e espaços.
Depois vão em "C:\Users\Seu_Usuario\\.kettle" e apaguem o arquivo "repositories",
por fim, reiniciem o PDI.